# Prove that sample auto-variance coefficient of stationary time series approaches to true autocovariance as n approaches infinity

Tags: self-study, covariance

[image]

Can you provide a hint on how to approach this ?. Here's what i got so far:[image]

Comment: At some point you need to introduce a definition of $\gamma(h):$ what is it?

Comment: I think that will be true autocovariance. The question asks me to show the sample autocovariance approaches true autocovariance as n approaches infinity

Comment: Yes, we know it's the true autocovariance.  What I am suggesting is that you introduce some formula for it into your analysis, because that will be very useful in guiding you.

Comment: Thanks. That's where i got stuck. I need to introduce true autocovariance in my equation somehow. Till now i can't think of any relation.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).